# Signification of $\varepsilon(h)$ and $|||A|||$

Tags: derivatives, optimization, error-function

Consider $f:x\in \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow f(x):= \frac{1}{2}x^\top Ax +b^\top x,$ with $n\geq 1$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

Check that the gradient does fulfill the following fundamental property

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d f(x+h) = f(x) + \langle\nabla f(x), h\rangle + o(\|\textbf{h}\|) (\textbf{h}\in \mathbb{R}^d)
$$
Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^d, h\in \mathbb{R}^d, h\ne O_d$
\begin{align*}
f(x+h) &= \frac{1}{2}(x+h)^\top A(x+h) + b^\top(x+h) \\
&=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}x^\top Ax + b^\top x}_{f(x)} + \underbrace{\frac{x^\top Ah}{2}+\frac{h^\top Ax}{2}}_{\frac{(x^\top Ah)^\top+h^\top Ax}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}h^\top Ah+\underbrace{b^\top h}_{h^\top b}\\
\text{and we know that: }& (x^\top Ah)^\top = xA^\top h^\top\\
\text{and we can write: }&\frac{x^\top Ah}{2}+\frac{h^\top Ax}{2} + h^\top b = \underbrace{h^\top\big[(A^\top + A)x + b\big]}_{\langle h, \nabla f(x) \rangle}
\end{align*}
We need to prove that: $\frac{1}{2}h^\top Ah = o(\|h\|) \Leftrightarrow \exists \varepsilon(h) \xrightarrow[h \rightarrow 0]{}0 $, $\|h\|\varepsilon (h) = \frac{h^\top Ah}{2}$
$$
\frac{1}{2}h^\top Ah = \frac{\|h\|^2}{2}\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)^\top A\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big) = \|h\|\underbrace{\big[\frac{\|h\|}{2}\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)^\top A\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)\big]}_{\varepsilon(h)}
$$
and  $\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)^\top A\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)$ is bounded for all $h$ by $|||A||| = \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d, \|x\|=1} x^\top A x$
$$
\epsilon (h) = \|h\|\cdot\big|\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)^\top A \big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)\big| \leq \|h\| \cdot |||A|||
$$
Therefore $\frac{1}{2}h^\top Ah = \|h\|\cdot \epsilon(h)  \frac{\rightarrow}{h \rightarrow 0} 0= o(\|h\|)$

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d f(x+h) = f(x) + \langle\nabla f(x), h\rangle + o(\|\textbf{h}\|)$

**Here are my 2 questions**:

1) where does the definition $\varepsilon(h) = \big[\frac{\|h\|}{2}\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)^\top A\big(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\big)\big]$ come from?

2) Is the following equivalent to the definition of the matrix norm: $|||A|||^{*4} = \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d, \|x\|=1} x^\top A x$. If yes, to which norm is it equivalent?

**one norm**
$$\|\textbf{A}\|_{1} = \max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n}{\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{m}|x_{i,j}|\Big)} = \quad \text{maximal column sum}$$

**infinity norm**
$$\|\textbf{A}\|_{\infty} = \max\limits_{1 \leq j \leq m}{\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_{i,j}|\Big)} = \quad \text{maximal row sum} $$

**two norm**
the most important norm $\|\textbf{A}\| = \|\textbf{A}\|_{2}$ is not easily computed.
$$\text{If $\textbf{A}$ is ssymmetric }\:\to \:\|\textbf{A}\|_{2} = \max\limits_{i}|\lambda_i|$$

Comment: what is the matrix $A$ you're referring to? also, the fundamental property you wish to verify is pretty much the definition of $f$ being differentiable at $x$.

Comment: thank you for your comment @peek-a-boo. I forgot to add the definition of the $f(x)$ where $A$ appears. I just added at the beginning of the problem

Comment: I see, but do you know the multivariable chain rule and the definition of differentiability? Because $f$ can be expressed as a composition of differentiable functions, and hence the gradient satisfies that fundamental property. If you try to do this the direct brute force method, you'll in essence be proving the chain rule in a special case, and very likely make a mistake if you're not careful (because the chain rule proof has some technicalities regarding the size of the error terms).

Comment: @peek-a-boo. yes I know the multivariable chain rule and the definition of differentiability. I also understand the proof. What I don't understand is where the definition of $\varepsilon$ and $|||A|||$ come from

Comment: You wish to show that $\dfrac{1}{2} h^t Ah = o(\lVert h \rVert)$. So if you multiply and divide by the norm of $h$, then  $\dfrac{1}{2} h^t Ah = \lVert h \rVert \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{\lVert h \rVert} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} h^t Ah \right) $, so the thing inside brackets is what you call $\varepsilon(h)$, and is what you want to show satisfies $\lim_{h \to 0} \varepsilon(h) = 0$. But is there any particular reason you're following this line of reasoning? because it seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Ok many thanks @peek-a-boo. I got the first part of the question. Now  where does the notation $|||A||| = \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d, \|x\|=1} x^\top A x$$ come from. Is it something different from the norm of a matrix?

Comment: that's not even a norm, because if $A= -\text{Id}$, then $x^tAx = - \lVert x \rVert^2$, so taking the maximum over all unit $x$ is yields $|||A||| = -1 < 0$, which shouldn't happen for a norm. On the other hand, $\sup \{\lVert Ax \rVert: 
\lVert x \rVert = 1 \}$ does define a norm for $A$, called the operator norm (if you want you can replace $\sup$ with $\max$, because the unit ball is compact and $x \mapsto Ax$ is continuous). But in any case, all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, so it doesn't matter which norm you use.

Comment: Ok that definitely brings some more insight. Thank you @peek-a-boo! Now is there a particular name to $|||A|||$ so that I can it up more precisely?

Comment: I'm not aware of any name for $|||A|||$ as you have defined it.

Comment: @peek-a-boo. You were saying that it is unnecessarily complicated. In fact I copied the answer of the exercise. Do you have a simpler explanation?

Comment: do you know that the inner product function  $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: \Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ is differentiable? (because it is a bounded bilinear map)

Comment: because if you do, then you can express $f$ as a sum and composition of differentiable functions, and hence $f$ is differentiable, so the gradient definitely satsifies that property. An even simpler explanantion is that $f$ is simply a polynomial in the $n$ variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$, and hence all partial derivatives of all orders exist. i.e $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ and hence (trivially) is differentiable. Therefore the gradient satisfies that property .